# distributed file reconciliation

Tags: python

We have the requirement to do reconciliation on Linux pair machines. Each pair(Machine M1 and machine M2) have  data stored in custom file format. Ideally machines in same pair are supposed to have identical data(equal nuumber of files and matching data) but due to some reason it doesn't happen.hence need to do reconciliation. 
What are the possible option to do this? Requirement is this process should run on each machine and should do
 1) comparison of  total number of files 
2) missing files(if file is missing on any machine, it must be copied from another machine . Each file size varies from 5KB to 200KB.
3)File will stored upto depth four /customer/P1/P2/P3/customeFile.dat
Possible options i m aware of: 
1) Write daemon  program in PERL/Python running on each machine. This process will do SSH on other and get  the data.
2)Write Java program and use of JMS to communicate with each other.
What are the better options?

Comment: yes. But not just syncing but also stuff like missing files need to be calculated.

Comment: right, [`rsync`](http://rsync.samba.org/)?